# "Unsubscribe from emails like this" and "Edit email settings" links broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

In the latest Developer Survey email from Stack Overflow, sent Jan 24, 2019, both the email preference links at the bottom result in "Invalid Request". "Leave Feedback" works as expected. I was able to reproduce this on Android (Gmail app) and on a desktop. Please see the images below. I'm not sure how to check if this is just me or universal.

[image: Links in question]

[image: Resulting message]

Comment: I would include the links but they resolve to a redirect that includes my email.

Comment: That's weird. Thanks for the heads up. We can't repro it with our initial check, but we're investigating.

Comment: If it's useful, is there a way I can privately send you the link in my email?

Comment: thanks but it looks like the real pros figured it out - appreciate the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex, we made a mistake when we were setting up our email campaign, and we sincerely apologize. The issue affected a few dozen people, including yourself.

We are unsubscribing you (and others affected) on the backend, so you won't receive additional emails like this unless you explicitly opt in at a later date.

Thank you for your patience.